# SQL: add a column that shows the total number of invalid ages

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this,

| user_id | age |
| --- | --- |
| First | 101 |
| Second | 22 |
| Third | 85 |
| Fourth | 111 |
| Fifth | 109 |

I just need to add another column that shows the total number of ages above 100. Something similar to below:

| user_id | age | invalid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 101 | 3 |
| Second | 22 | 3 |
| Third | 85 | 3 |
| Fourth | 111 | 3 |
| Fifth | 109 | 3 |

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, countif(age > 100) over() invalid
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]